# ExtJs: Store populated by Grid comes up as blank

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-stores

I am using an ArrayStore and filling it up by adding model records. 
This store is associated with a data grid.

Now the arraystore object is getting filled perfectly fine but the data is not coming up in the grid. In fact, on debugging, I found that the store of the grid (`datagrid.store`) also has the data, but still it does not display it on the screen!!

Following is my code.

**Model:**

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.window.visualsqlquerybuilder.SQLAttributeValueModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
    {
        name: 'attribute',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {   name: 'attributeValue',
        type: 'string'
    }
  ]
});
```

**Store:**

```
var attrValueStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'Ext.ux.window.visualsqlquerybuilder.SQLAttributeValueModel'
});
```

**Grid**

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.window.visualsqlquerybuilder.SQLAttributeValueGrid', {
//requires: ['Ext.ux.CheckColumn'],
autoRender: true,
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: ['widget.attributevaluegrid'],
id: 'SQLAttributeValueGrid',
store: attrValueStore,
columnLines: true,
plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 1
})],
columns: [        
    {                        /*Expression */
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        text: 'Attribute',
        sortable: false,
        menuDisabled: true,
        flex: 0.225,
        dataIndex: 'attribute'
    },
    {                           /*Attribute Values*/
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        editor: 'textfield',
        text: 'Values',
        flex: 0.225,
        dataIndex: 'attributeValue'
    }
],
initComponent: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

**Modal Window displaying the grid**

```
var attributeValueForm = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
title:'Missing Attribute Values',
id: 'attributeValueForm',
height:500,
width:400,
modal:true,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
closeAction: 'hide',
items:[
    {
        xtype: 'attributevaluegrid',
        border: false,
        //height: 80,
        region: 'center',
        split: true
    }
],
buttons: [
    {
        id: 'OKBtn',
        itemId: 'OKBtn',
        text: 'OK',
        handler: function () {
            Ext.getCmp('attributeValueForm').close();
        }
    },
    {
        text: 'Cancel',
        handler: function () {
            Ext.getCmp('attributeValueForm').close();
        }
    }
]
});
```

Now at the time of displaying the modal window, I checked the value of the store object as well as the store inside the grid object. Both are having the proper data.

**But when the window opens, I am getting a blank grid**

Comment: You're never loading the store anywhere. You don't assign it a proxy or give it inline data. The store is empty.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: I understand your point but I actually missed out on adding the code for adding the data into the store. I am doing it separately in another method wherein I create a model object, set values for its properties and add it into the store. So the store has the data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to load the store data... try with:

```
var attrValueStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
    autoSync: true,
    autoLoad : true,
    model: 'Ext.ux.window.visualsqlquerybuilder.SQLAttributeValueModel'
});
```

Comment: Following on from this it may be necessary at times to load the grid dynamically as sometimes when the store is ready (this is when autoload occurs) we may not have the relevant params available for the store.

To load the store from anywhere in your app you can use

`Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('<store_itemid>').load()` where the value in angle brackets is the itemid of your store.

Hope this helps

Baz